# How can i scale down an image to a window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, scale, graphics2d

I have a window, and i want to draw a BufferedImage inside the window, but scaled down, and i want it to always change when i resize the window.

The dx1, and dx2 should be the destionation X position, and the dy1, and dy2 should be the destionation Y position. (I don't know these four)
The sx1, and sx2 should be the source X position, and the sy1, and sy2 should be the destionation Y position. (0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight() because i want to use the full image)

```java
gr.drawImage(image, dx1, dx2, dy1, dy2, sx1, sx2, sy1, sy2, null);
```

I will need 2 paddings i think (p1, p2), and the **windowWidth is the width of the JPanel, and the windowHeight is the height of the JPanel.**
That's my code:

```java
gr.drawImage(image, p1, p2, windowWidth-p1, windowHeight-p2, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) *"That's my code:"* [Edit] to add a [mre]. 2) Hotlink to an image. 3) `gr.drawImage(image, .. null);` should be `gr.drawImage(image, .. this);`